# Can't mock function multiple times react, testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, mocking, fetch

I want to test my component:

```
const Courses: React.FC = () => {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(
    'some url...',
    fetcher
  );

  console.log(data, error);

  if (error) {
    return (
      <CoursesContainer>
        <Error>Something went wrong.</Error>
      </CoursesContainer>
    );
  }

  if (!data) return <Loader title="loader" />;

  return (
    <CoursesContainer>
      <CollapsibleTable courses={data} />
    </CoursesContainer>
  );
};

export default Courses;
```

but I don't know why I can't mock it to return different value for each test. I've tried that:

```
jest.mock('../../utils/fetcher', () => ({
  fetcher: jest
    .fn()
    .mockReturnValue('default')
    .mockReturnValueOnce('first call')
    .mockReturnValueOnce('second call'),
  readData: jest.fn(),
}));

test('Basic render. fetch pending', async () => {
  const component = render(<Courses />);
  await waitFor(() => component.findByTitle('loader'));
  expect(component.baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
});

test('Basic render, fetch success', async () => {
  const component = render(<Courses />);
  await waitFor(() => component.findByText('CollapsibleTable'));
  expect(component.baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
});

test('Basic render, fetch error', async () => {
  const component = render(<Courses />);
  await waitFor(() => component.findByText('Something went wrong.'));
  expect(component.baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

and that doesn't work well. For each of tests there is only `first call` console.log() - The       `console.log(data, error);` from Courses.tsx.
The feedback from jest:

```
  console.log
    undefined undefined

      at Courses (src/components/Courses.tsx:14:11)

  console.log
    first call undefined

      at Courses (src/components/Courses.tsx:14:11)

  console.log
    first call undefined

      at Courses (src/components/Courses.tsx:14:11)

  console.log
    first call undefined

      at Courses (src/components/Courses.tsx:14:11)
```

And of course the third test (`Basic render, fetch error`) is failed cos of that.

I can't use `spyOn()` instead, cos of my `fetcher` is separate function whithout object.

@@ UPDATE @@

There are my `fetcher` and `readData` functions:

```
const fetcher = (url: string) => {
  return fetch(url)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data: Array<IFetchData>) => readData(data));
};

const readData = (data: Array<IFetchData>) => {
  let myData: Array<ICourse> = [];

  [ there are some simple operations which create new myData array with 
    properties which I need (there is not any async operations)]

  return myData;
};
```

Comment: Is `fetcher` and `readData` returns promise?

Comment: I've just added these functions to question at the bottom

Comment: You can't achieve what you want. See the updated answer. @poldeeek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give mock implementation for `readData` as well.

According to jest specification,

> We can create a mock function with jest.fn(). If no implementation is given, the mock function will return undefined when invoked.

---

This will make more sense about your test.

```
 await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => component.getByTitle('loader'));
```

We're waiting for the loader title to be removed which ensures that the title shows up in the first place and now it is removed when loader is completed.

```
jest.mock('../../utils/fetcher', () => ({
  fetcher: jest
    .fn()
    .mockResolvedValue('default')
    .mockResolvedValueOnce('first call')
    .mockResolvedValueOnce('second call'),
  readData: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('Read call'), //provide reseolve value
//jest.fn() returns undefined when we dont't provide implementation
}));

test('Basic render. fetch pending', async () => {
  const component = render(<Courses />);
  await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => component.getByTitle('loader'));
  expect(component.baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
});

test('Basic render, fetch success', async () => {
  const component = render(<Courses />);
  await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => component.getByText('CollapsibleTable'));
  expect(component.baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
});

test('Basic render, fetch error', async () => {
  const component = render(<Courses />);
  await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => component.getByText('Something went wrong.'));
  expect(component.baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

@Updated answer

> > Sorry to say that you can't achieve what you want. The reason is the render function is called only once in your test case so it means that the `fetcher` and `readData` API will call only once.

```
const mockFn = jest.fn();
jest.mock('../../utils/fetcher', () => ({
  fetcher: mockFn.mockResolvedValueOnce('first call'),
  readData: mockFn.mockResolvedValue(['Read call']), // returns array
}));
```

```
test('Basic render. fetch pending', async () => {
  const component = render(<Courses />);
  await waitForElementToBeRemoved(() => component.getByTitle('loader'));
  expect(mockFn).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // test passed
  expect(component.baseElement).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Even your provide mockResolvedValueOnce again it will give `undefined` as render function doesn't get a chance to call the second time to mock version of `fetcher` and `readData`.

Comment: Thanks for the `waitForElementToBeRemoved` function advice :) Still there is the same problem with the mocking. Mock `readData()` didn't fix the problem. I've just added both the `readData` and `fetcher` at the bottom of my question.

Comment: Yea... I've just figure this out by myself :v I've tried a couple `mockImplementationOnce`, but for component which is rendered in each of test there will be only first `mockImplementationOnce` call :/

Comment: btw this is the best example of mocking API . Now, most people have started using `MSW` for mocking api.

Comment: I wrote that application only for learn and fun purposes, so I will check that `Mock Service Worker` solution for sure :) Thanks for your time anyway

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your MockReturnValue chain is out of order. The default should be last, like this:

```
jest.mock('../../utils/fetcher', () => ({
  fetcher: jest
    .fn()
    .mockReturnValueOnce('first call')
    .mockReturnValueOnce('second call')
    .mockReturnValue('default'),
  readData: jest.fn(),
}));
```

See the approved answer from here:
[Jest mock the same function twice with different arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53887173/jest-mock-the-same-function-twice-with-different-arguments/60095478)

Comment: Hmm... could you post the code for the fetcher module? Might make it easier to diagnose.

Comment: I've just added these functions (`fetcher` and `readData`) to question at the bottom